# Postgresql server won't start, error: cannot change owner or permissions

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, wsl-2

I setup ubuntu 18.04 in windows wsl2 originally it but on installing postgresql11 the server shows down during install when I try and start the server with "systemctl start postgresql" I got

> "system has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). can't operate."

I found out cause windows uses systeminit, so use " service postgresql start", only this generates

> "chmod: changing permissions of 'var/run/postgresql': operation not permitted."

If i try "service postgresql restart" I get the error:

> "install: cannot change owner and permissions of '/var/run/postgrest': No such file or directory Error: could not create /var/run/postgresql/11-main.pg_stat_tmp: no such file or directory."

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no improvement. I was trying to find postgres.config to see if i had a port issue but i cant find the files for postgresql

Comment: i have not worked with wsl but maybe running the commands with sudo gives you the needed privilege. the commands you mentioned need sudo privilege to be executed under native linux

Comment: https://cloudcone.com/docs/article/how-to-install-postgresql-11-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the help, I got it working. I completely uninstalled postgresql11, then I installed postgresql13 cause why not 11 wasn't working right anyways and for what I'm doing I don't need a specific version number. After that I ran

sudo -i -u postgres
service postgresql start

and wallah.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ownership of `/var/run/postgres` to the operating system user that runs PostgreSQL. I wouldn't use Windows' Linux emulation for serious database work.

Answer (score 0):

Since [systemd](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/) is available with WSL, there is a fix!

In your WSL distro [add](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-enable-systemd-in-wsl/)

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

to `/etc/wsl.conf` and restart the distro.
Postgresql should run already at startup, check

```
systemctl status postgresql@15-main
```